# I need a word to describe a word

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, vocabulary

I need a word that describes how some words have irrelevant meanings.
Such as hot fast cold etc. what is hot to one person is not hot to another. What is hot? 100 degrees 1000 degrees. I knew this word long ago and can’t remember and it’s driving me crazy

Comment: You should include a sample sentence demonstrating how this word would be used.

Comment: Beauty is in the eyes of the beholder.